# How can I group rows that aren't familiar?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, charts

My data looks like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1266b2/1

But I want it to look like:

```
+------------+------+---+
| 2015-01-01 | walk | 1 |
| 2015-01-01 | run  | 0 |
| 2015-01-01 | bike | 0 |
| 2015-01-02 | walk | 0 |
| 2015-01-02 | run  | 0 |
| 2015-01-02 | bike | 0 |
| 2015-01-03 | walk | 0 |
| 2015-01-03 | run  | 1 |
| 2015-01-03 | bike | 0 |
| 2015-01-04 | walk | 0 |
| 2015-01-04 | run  | 0 |
| 2015-01-04 | bike | 0 |
| 2015-01-05 | walk | 0 |
| 2015-01-05 | run  | 1 |
| 2015-01-05 | bike | 0 |
+------------+------+---+
```

Each day should have a collection of how many occurrences of each event response happened.

- The dates are collected from a calendar table and are thus purely static.
- The event names are numerous and likely to change.
- Event responses join events for name and other context rules.

Would be a big help to figure this out. At least offer tips for better title (search terms) so I can figure out how to resolve this issue.

This is for processing graphs at [activezoo.com](https://activezoo.com). Any advice for other approaches or methods for analyzing data is very welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want every date/event combination and you want to count the # of event responses. If so, use a `cross join` between the `calendar` and the `event` table to get every combination and then `left join` to the `event_responses` table and count a column from that table so you only count matches.

```
SELECT calendar.date AS date, events.name AS event, COUNT(event_responses.date) AS count 
FROM events
CROSS JOIN calendar
LEFT JOIN event_responses ON event_responses.event_id = events.id
AND event_responses.date = calendar.date
GROUP BY calendar.date, event
ORDER BY calendar.date, event
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2560/1

Comment: Beat me to it dang it! Nice answer. I'd point out that if you have a lot of data Cross Join can take some time to process but in this instance it is perfect.